# QGIS Sieve Tool in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is there an ArcMap equivalent to the Sieve Tool found in QGIS?

> Sieve Tool:  This utility removes raster polygons smaller than a
>   provided threshold size (in pixels) and replaces them with the pixel
>   value of the largest neighbor polygon.